# Rails STI. How do I count the number of votes of type Upvote or Downvote for associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

Models are `Vote` and `Issue`. `Issue has_many :votes`. `Vote` has a STI column type that is filled with either `:Upvote` or `:Downvote` by a hidden form on the Issues index when a user votes on an issue. How do I find the number of votes of either type `Upvote` or `Downvote` for a given issue? Right now I'm using a method on the `Issue` model like this:

```
 def upvotes_count(issue_id)
     Upvote.count(:conditions => "issue_id = #{issue_id}")
 end

def downvotes_count(issue_id)
      Downvote.count(:conditions => "issue_id = #{issue_id}")
end
```

I pass the issue_id from the view when I cycle through all the issues on the Issues index like this:

```
issue.upvotes_count(issue.id)
```

Is this right or is there a better way? Doesn't seem like I should have to pass the id when I'm already operating on an instance. I've played around in the console trying to figure it out but can't figure it out. I know `@issue.Upvote.count` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options: define additional associations (or methods) in the `Issue` class, or use `scope` in the `Vote` class. These examples assume Rails 3, though they can be easily adjusted for Rails 2.3.

1. Additional associations in `Issue`:

   ```
   class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_many :votes
     has_many :upvotes, :class_name => "Vote", :conditions => ['type = ?', 'Upvote']
     has_many :downvotes, :class_name => "Vote", :conditions => ['type = ?', 'Downvote']

   end
   ```

   Here, we add conditions to refine the results of associated votes on an issue so you can call `issue.upvotes` and `issue.downvotes`. To get the count of upvotes on an issue is, in this case, `issue.upvotes.count`.
2. Scope in `Vote`:

   ```
   class Vote

     scope :up, where(:type => 'Upvote')
     scope :down, where(:type => 'Downvote')

   end
   ```

   The `up` and `down` scopes in Vote provide methods on vote relations so you can call `issue.votes.up` and `issue.votes.down`. To get the count of upvotes on an issue is simply `issue.votes.up.count`.